# task returned by IHttpActionResult.ExecuteAsync() overload is not run

Tags: c#, owin, webapi2, self-host-webapi

I'm trying to create a self-hosted Web service that starts its server with `Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start<NotifyStartup>("http://localhost:9000/")` and contains a controller derived from `System.Net.Http.ApiController`. `NotifyStartup` looks like this:

```
using System.Web.Http;
using Owin;
...
class NotifyStartup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}
```

The controller has this URI handler:

```
using System.Web.Http;
...
[Route("notify")]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Notify([FromBody]object body)
{
    return new HttpAction();
}
```

Here's HttpAction:

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
...
public class HttpAction : IHttpActionResult
{
    public HttpAction() { }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return new Task<HttpResponseMessage>(() =>
        {
            var rspContent = "here's a response string";
            var rsp = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rspContent))
            {
                rsp.Content = new StringContent(rspContent);
            }
            return rsp;
        }, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

(At some point `HttpAction` will pay attention to `Notify()`'s `body` parameter and  `rspContent` will be assigned something requiring some database lookups, which is why I'm trying to make this work asynchronously.)

When I run the program and POST to http://localhost:9000/notify/ the URI handler is called, it creates an `HttpAction` instance and that instance's `ExecuteAsync()` method is called. However, the task it returns is never run, and the client hangs waiting for a response. If I change `ExecuteAsync()` so that the work is done synchronously and the response returned in a wrapper task:

```
var rspContent = "here's a response string";
var rsp = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rspContent))
{
    rsp.Content = new StringContent(rspContent);
}
return Task.FromResult(rsp);
```

that wrapper task *is* run and the client receives its response.

As far as I know, the tasks created by `new Task<>...` and `Task.FromResult()` should look identical to the caller. Why will it `await` (or whatever it's actually doing to obtain the result) one and not the other? What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the tasks created by `new Task<>` and `Task.FromResult()` should look
>   identical to the caller.

They do look identical from the caller perspective, but they aren't the same from the implementation perspective.

The `Task` constructor doesn't start the task, that's why you shouldn't use it. Instead use `Task.Run` which returns a hot task:

```
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var rspContent = "here's a response string";
        var rsp = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rspContent))
        {
            rsp.Content = new StringContent(rspContent);
        }
        return rsp;
    }, cancellationToken);
}
```

Although I'd argue that this may be redundant by itself, since an action in WebAPI by itself is already ran on a thread pool thread, it is usually redundant to wrap it around inside an additional thread.

Comment: There's something I didn't know I didn't know, and another reason not to like .NET. Coming from C++ I assumed that where and when a task (future) is run was up to the run-time, and that calling for its result was enough to ensure it would run, synchronously or asynchronously. Given that my only choice here is to explicitly schedule it on the thread pool it would probably be better for me just to ensure that, if possible, all I/O-bound calls I make are asynchronous and forgo creating an actual, thread-runnable task.

Comment: @EvanBurkitt If your operation is IO bound, you don't need to use `Task.Run` at all, you need to look at ["async-await"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx) and utilize API which themselves expose async endpoints, such as `HttpClient` for making asynchronous HTTP calls.

Comment: yes, that's what I meant. I should make `await` calls to async functions instead of creating tasks. Async programming in C# seems to be an odd mixture of low level (decision of how and when tasks run must be made explicitly) and high level (magic continuations created by `await` operator). I'm not sure I like it, but I'll get used to it. I appreciate your help.